# How to configure reverse proxy in apache2 for embedded tomcat server in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache2, reverse-proxy

I am trying to configure reverse proxy for spring boot app, but it is not working. It serves the html page from www/example.com instead of serving content from spring boot app.

Here is my application.properties

```
server.address=127.0.0.1
server.port=8080
server.servlet.context-path=/
server.use-forward-headers=true
server.tomcat.remote_ip_header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol_header=x-forwarded-proto
```

This is my example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ProxyPreserveHost On
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
Redirect / https://www.example.com/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>    
SSLEngine On
SSLProxyEngine On
ServerName example.com
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf    
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are your logfiles showing something?

Comment: @alexzimmer96 no, there is nothing related to proxy in logfiles

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing the

```
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

in the https virtualhost configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out that there was file named example.com-le-ssl.conf that was overwriting the configuration in example.com.conf so, I just copied the configuration from example.com.conf in example.com-le-ssl.conf and it worked. My guess is example.com-le-ssl.conf was created when I added ssl certificate.